# How to check if all objects of array are included another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I am trying to check if object `array A` includes `objects` from `B`.

```
let A = [
    { name: "Max" },
    { name: "Jhon" },
    { name: "Naton" },
]

let B = [
    { name: "Max" },
    { name: "Naton" },
]
```

So `B` has two `objects` that is in `array A`. How to check this ?

I am trying to achieve it with `includes` :

```
  for(let entry of this.b){
      if(this.a.includes(entry)){
        console.log('includes');
      }
    }
```

But I get `false` on `includes`.

Comment: that'r right, you have all different objects with some same property values.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want that I could check if array A contains array's B objects. So the output would be console.log('includes') for each similar object in both arrays.

Comment: you have to check the values of the property

Comment: How to check if all values are the same ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: I want to edit those similar objects in object array A - add new keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Array.includes()` compare the entries of the array with the given value. Because your array entries are objects, it will not match. You have to loop at the array yourself and make the comparison.

`Array.some()` loops on an array and returns true if you returns true at least one. This method is useful when you want to verify something. In our example, we want to verify if the array a contains the b entry.

```js
const a = [{
    name: 'Max',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jhon',
  },
  {
    name: 'Naton',
  },
];

const b = [{
    name: 'Max',
  },
  {
    name: 'Naton',
  },
  {
    name: 'Daddy',
  },
];

console.log(b.map(x => a.some(y => y.name === x.name)));
```

---

If I break it down :

```js
const a = [{
    name: 'Max',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jhon',
  },
  {
    name: 'Naton',
  },
];

const b = [{
    name: 'Max',
  },
  {
    name: 'Naton',
  },
  {
    name: 'Daddy',
  },
];

// Loop on every entry of the b array
b.forEach((x) => {
  // x here represent one entry
  // first it will worth { name: 'Max' }, then { name: 'Naton' } ...
  // for each value we are going to look at a if we can find a match
  const isThereAMatch = a.some((y) => {
    // y here is worth one entry of the a array
    if (y.name === x.name) return true;

    return false;
  });

  if (isThereAMatch === true) {
    console.log(`We have found ${x.name} in a`);
  } else {
    console.log(`We have not found ${x.name} in a`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use another loop, then check the property name:

```js
var a = [
  {name: "Max"},
  {name: "Jhon"},
  {name: "Naton"},
];
var b = [
  {name: "Max"},
  {name: "Naton"},
];

for(let entry of b){
  for(let entry2 of a){
    if(entry2.name == entry.name){
      console.log('includes', entry.name);
    }
  }
}
```

**OR:** You can use string version of object to check with `includes()`:

```js
var a = [
  {name: "Max"},
  {name: "Jhon"},
  {name: "Naton"},
];
var b = [
  {name: "Max"},
  {name: "Naton"},
];
var aTemp = a.map(i => JSON.stringify(i));
var bTemp = b.map(i => JSON.stringify(i));
for(let entry of bTemp){
  if(aTemp.includes(entry)){
    console.log('includes', entry);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use **[`Array#includes()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** it will always return `false` **because it's comparing `objects` which aren't equal** because they aren't referencing the same `object`.

You should compare objects `properties` and not whole objects, you can do it using **[`Array#some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** like this:

```
for (let entry of this.b) {
  if (this.b.some(x => x.name === entry.name)) {
    console.log('includes');
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
A = [{
    name: "Max"
  },
  {
    name: "Jhon"
  },
  {
    name: "Naton"
  },
]

B = [{
    name: "Max"
  },
  {
    name: "Naton"
  },
]

//Filter objects that exists in both arrays
let result = A.filter(el=> B.some(x => x.name === el.name));
console.log(result);
```